# How can I refactor this code with the strategy pattern?

Tags: ruby, strategy-pattern

I have a lot of validations. I am refactoring this code:

```
  if is_manager?
    # if cond1
    # if cond2
    # if cond3
  end

  if is_admin?
    # if cond4
    # if cond5
    # if cond6
  end

  def is_user?
    # if cond9
    # if cond8
    # if cond7
  end
```

I want to apply different strategies based on the kind of user that is making the action. I am thinking to create strategies for different users, but I am missing how I can avoid all these `if`s.

I have come up with something like this.

```
  v = Validator.new # my context object
  v.add(Validation::ManagerStategy.new) if is_manager?
  v.add(Validation::AdminStategy.new) if is_admin?
  v.add(Validation::UserStategy.new) if is_user?
  v.validate()
```

But I am not sure whether I am implementing it in the right way.

Comment: At a glance, your proposed solution looks alright to me.

Comment: Are you working with any ORM such as ActiveRecord or just plain ruby class?

Comment: @DjezzzL I am using sequel, an alternative to ActiveRecord. why?

Comment: @ciaoben so why not use the way which [sequal uses](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/validations_rdoc.html)?

Comment: @DjezzzL because I am not talking about simple "data-related" validation, but mostly business logic and verification of conditions are met in the system for the operation. (e.g limits, permissions, etc..)

Comment: How is `is_manager?` and `is_user?` implemented - if you want to avoid if-else, one way is to have Hash of user-type to validator instance map